# Is there a command to get the largest 5 values and smallest 5 in Stata?

Tags: command, stata

I'm investigating coronavirus impact on each country and created a variable that is the average amount of cases per country. Now I have to get the 5 countries with the biggest and smallest amount of cases in average. Does anyone know how I can do this in Stata?

Answer (score 3):

If there are no missing values, in general you can `sort` on the variable of interest and look at the first 5 and last 5 observations, as in

```
. sort whatever 
. list whatever country if inrange(_n, 1, 5) | inrange(_n, _N - 4, _N)
```

See `extremes` from SSC for an application that ignores missing values if they exist and has extra hooks:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ssc install extremes

. extremes mpg

  +------------+
  | obs:   mpg |
  |------------|
  |  26.    12 |
  |  27.    12 |
  |  11.    14 |
  |  12.    14 |
  |  28.    14 |
  +------------+

  +------------+
  |  68.    31 |
  |  43.    34 |
  |  57.    35 |
  |  66.    35 |
  |  71.    41 |
  +------------+

note: 6 values of 14

. extremes mpg make

  +--------------------------------+
  | obs:   mpg   make              |
  |--------------------------------|
  |  26.    12   Linc. Continental |
  |  27.    12   Linc. Mark V      |
  |  11.    14   Cad. Deville      |
  |  12.    14   Cad. Eldorado     |
  |  28.    14   Linc. Versailles  |
  +--------------------------------+

  +-----------------------------+
  |  68.    31   Toyota Corolla |
  |  43.    34   Plym. Champ    |
  |  57.    35   Datsun 210     |
  |  66.    35   Subaru         |
  |  71.    41   VW Diesel      |
  +-----------------------------+

note: 6 values of 14
```